# Code doesn't function on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I made a website, nothing special, just learning how JavaScript works.

On **Desktop** it works really good. When I make my JavaScript look like this

```
function menu(){
menuButton = document.getElementById('button_menu');
nav = document.getElementById('menu');
content = document.getElementById('content');

if (menuButton.classList != 'active'){
    //Then Move Content and Nav
    menuButton.classList.add('active');

    content.classList.remove('moveContentBack');
    content.classList.add('moveContent');

    nav.classList.remove('moveNavBack');
    nav.classList.add('moveNav');
}
else{
    menuButton.classList.remove('active');

    content.classList.remove('moveContent');
    content.classList.add('moveContentBack');

    nav.classList.remove('moveNav');
    nav.classList.add('moveNavBack');

}
}
```

On **Mobile** the code works better this way.

```
function menu(){
menuButton = document.getElementById('button_menu');
nav = document.getElementById('menu');
content = document.getElementById('content');

if (menuButton.classList != 'active'){
    //Then Move Content and Nav
    menuButton.classList.add('active');

    content.style.webkitTransform = "translate3d(200px, 0px, 0)";
    nav.style.webkitTransform = "translate3d(0px, 0px, 0)";
}
else{
    menuButton.classList.remove('active');

    content.style.webkitTransform = "translate3d(0px, 0px, 0)";
    nav.style.webkitTransform = "translate3d(-100px, 0px, 0)";
}
}
```

I really like how it is on the **Desktop**

For some reason it simply doesn't work like that. If you would like a preview of my website, see how it working (on mobile and desktop), check out skarchmittest2.tumblr.com

I know I can make it universal and make it simple transition, but I added those classes to make it kind of bouncing.

```
.active{
background: red !important;
}
.moveContent{
-webkit-animation: moveContentBounce .5s;
animation: moveContentBounce .5s;
/*-webkit-transform: translate3d(200px, 0px, 0) !important;*/
}
.moveContentBack{
-webkit-animation: moveContentBackBounce .5s;
animation: moveContentBackBounce .5s;
/*-webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0) !important;*/
}
.moveNav{
-webkit-animation: moveNav .5s;
animation: moveNav .5s;
/*-webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0) !important;*/
}
.moveNavBack{
-webkit-animation: moveNavBack .5s;
animation: moveNavBack .5s;
/*-webkit-transform: translate3d(-100px, 0px, 0)!important;*/
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveContentBounce{
0%{-webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0);}
50%{-webkit-transform: translate3d(230px, 0px, 0);}
 100%{-webkit-transform: translate3d(200px, 0px, 0);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveContentBackBounce{
0%{-webkit-transform: translate3d(200px, 0px, 0);}
20%{-webkit-transform: translate3d(210px, 0px, 0);}
100%{-webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0);}
 }

@-webkit-keyframes moveContent{
0%{-webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0);}
/*50%{-webkit-transform: translate3d(100px, 0px, 0);}*/
100%{-webkit-transform: translate3d(200px, 0px, 0);}
 }

@-webkit-keyframes moveContentBack{
0%{-webkit-transform: translate3d(200px, 0px, 0);}
/*50%{-webkit-transform: translate3d(100px, 0px, 0);}*/
100%{-webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveNav{
0%{-webkit-transform: translate3d(-100px, 0px, 0);}
100%{-webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0);}
}
@-webkit-keyframes moveNavBack{
0%{-webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0);}
100%{-webkit-transform: translate3d(-100px, 0px, 0);}
}
```

and the original state of these objects

```
 #content{
    z-index: 100;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    transition: 0.2s ease-out;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}    
nav#menu{
position: absolute;
min-height: 100vh;
width: 300px;
background: gray;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(-100px, 0px, 0);
}
```

There is some commented out code and that is what I have attempted to make it work universally as it does on the desktop.

Basically, I am not sure why -webkit-transform **CSS PROPERTY** doesn't work on iOS, but using JavaScript and .style.webkitTrasform = ""; does. I will make it compatible with other browsers as well once I get this figured out.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure, but as you can see on http://caniuse.com/#search=webkit-transform, there's only partial support of webkit-transform for iOS. Quote from there:

> Partial support refers to lack of filter support or buggy result from
>   effects. A CSS Filter Effects specification is in the works that would
>   replace this method.

So maybe you have to keep the js-solution for a while.

Comment: I have figured it out, check my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my javascript, all I had to do was add

```
  window.location="#scroll"; 
  window.location="#someotherObject";
```

These two objects are invisible (opacity:0 and and not selectable), and positioned absolutely in the same place. Works like a charm.